# EOF in C.I keep getting ^Z?

Tags: c, eof

When i try to simulate EOF in Debug screen of my program,i use windows, i try with Ctrl+Z but it just prints ^Z on the screen?Does anyone knows how to solve this or how to signalise the end of file differently to my program?

Comment: Have you tried to press enter after Strg-Z?

Comment: try pressing two times `ctrl+Z`